# How to change primaryDarkColor in loolipop devices in android?

Tags: android

This is my code for 
**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```

and this is for
**styles.xml(v21)**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>

</style>
```

and this is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

problem is although my `primaryColor` is changing on both lollipop and pre-lollipop devices but my `primaryDarkColor` is not changing on `lollipop devices` to
what might be reason?

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: Try with removing your `styles.xml(v21)`.

Answer (score 0):

in **styles.xml(v21)** you have to remove item **colorPrimary, android:colorPrimaryDark, android:colorAccent  because you already define colorPrimary, android:colorPrimaryDark, android:colorAccent in AppTheme.Base.**

```
    //remove from styles.xml(v21)
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
```

Comment: Can it be because I have not used android:Theme.Material anywhere in my styles?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: I get this exception when I do what you suggetsed